# list items disappear when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so I'm trying to build an overlay for some randomly generated people. It's a project I'm working on where you req random users dynamically with some jQuery and AJAX and I've got that down and have them listed but I need to be able to click on them and they show up in like a modal window. That's where the problem is. When you click on them I have them displaying but they disappear on the page. What's causing this and how can I fix it?? Ignore the pacing of the modal I'm not worried about CSS rn.

```js
let html = "";

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5000',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    html += "<ul>"
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

      html += "<li>";
      html += "<img src=" + '"' + data.results[i].picture.medium + '">';
      html += "<div id='main'>"
      html += "<h3>" + data.results[i].name.first + " " + data.results[i].name.last + "</h3>";
      html += "<p>" + data.results[i].email + "</p>";
      html += "<p>" + data.results[i].location.city + "</p>";
      html += "<p class='popup'>" + data.results[i].phone + "</p>"
      html += "<p class='popup'>" + data.results[i].location.street + ", " + data.results[i].location.state + " " + data.results[i].location.postcode + "</p>";
      html += "<p class='popup'>" + data.results[i].dob + "</p>"
      html += "</div>";
      html += "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>"
    $("#employeeList").html(html);

    $("li").on("click", function() {
      $(".overlay").css("display", "block");
      $(".modal").html(this);
      $(".modal").preventDefault();
    });

    $(".overlay").on("click", function() {
      $(".overlay").css("display", "none");
    });

  }
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body,
html {
  background-color: #eff2f5;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
}

li img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px lightgray solid;
  min-width: 400px;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
}

p {
  color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#main {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal {
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
<h1>Awesome Startup Employee Directory</h1>
<div id="employeeList"></div>
```

Sorry About all the content but I'm stuck. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Can you put your example in a JSFiddle.net

Comment: Curious, why have an overlay if you hide it on click? `$(".overlay").on("click", function() {
      $(".overlay").css("display", "none");
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because your passing "this" to modal, so I believe it's better just to copy the content like this

```
    $("li").on("click", function () {
      var $li = '<li>' + this.innerHTML +'<li>';
      $(".overlay").css("display", "block");
      $(".modal").html($li);
      //$(".modal").preventDefault();
    });
```

```js
let html = ""; 

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5000',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    html += "<ul>"
    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

       html += "<li>";
       html += "<img src=" + '"' + data.results[i].picture.medium + '">';
       html += "<div id='main'>"
       html += "<h3>" + data.results[i].name.first + " " + data.results[i].name.last + "</h3>";
       html += "<p>" + data.results[i].email + "</p>";
       html += "<p>" + data.results[i].location.city + "</p>";
       html += "<p class='popup'>" + data.results[i].phone + "</p>"
       html += "<p class='popup'>" + data.results[i].location.street + ", " + data.results[i].location.state + " " + data.results[i].location.postcode + "</p>";
       html += "<p class='popup'>" + data.results[i].dob + "</p>"
       html += "</div>";
       html += "</li>";
    }   
      html += "</ul>"
      $("#employeeList").html(html);

    $("li").on("click", function () {
      var $li = '<li>' + this.innerHTML +'<li>';
     $(".overlay").css("display", "block");
     $(".modal").html($li);
     //$(".modal").preventDefault();
  });

    $(".overlay").on("click", function () {
     $(".overlay").css("display", "none");
  });

  }
});
```

```css
* {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body, html {
    background-color: #eff2f5;
    margin: 0;
}


ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 25px;

}

.popup {
    display: none;
}

li img {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


li {
   flex: 1; 
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin: 12px;
   border: 2px lightgray solid;
   min-width: 400px;
}

li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}

p {
    color: gray;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#main {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h3 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal {
    background-color: grey;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>AJAX Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="overlay">
     <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
 <h1>Awesome Startup Employee Directory</h1>
 <div id="employeeList"></div>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>    
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your `li` and pass in the copy instead of passing in the original `li` node. Also accept an `event` parameter in your callback and call `event.preventDefault` instead of `$(".modal").preventDefault` to get rid of `preventDefault is not a function` error.

```
$("li").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $(".overlay").css("display", "block");
    $(".modal").html($(this).clone());
});
```

Comment: LOL, I always forget Jquery can clone node

Comment: @AngelSalazar Haha. I guess it's the benefit of having an outside perspective. Since I don't use jquery, I had to type "jquery clone node" into google to find out the jquery way to do this. 

Answer (score 0):

Several things here you might change.

1. You have a global `i` in your loop
2. You have a duplicate `id='main'` in your loop producing invalid html, use a class
3. Not sure what the `.preventDefault();` is preventing...but it should be using the event perhaps?  I commented it out.
4. Why is your `html` declared outside the success?
5. Why have the event handler attachments inside the success event handler?
6. Inside the overlay event handler you search for it again, use `this`
7. It is often easier to use the `.show()` and `.hide()` than the css since you have jQuery already in play, add a `.hidden` class to hide initially.
8. Some semi-colons were missing - not a huge thing but why force the parser to insert them.
9. **You can clone a node and show its content somewhere else.**
10. `img src=` odd quote things, use single quotes

I also use variable `r` to make the code easier to read

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5000',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    let html = "";
    html += "<ul>";
    var i=0;
    for (i=0; i < 12; i++) {
      let r = data.results[i];
      html += "<li>";
      html += "<img src='" + r.picture.medium + "'>";
      html += "<div class='main'>";
      html += "<h3>" + r.name.first + " " + r.name.last + "</h3>";
      html += "<p>" + r.email + "</p>";
      html += "<p>" + r.location.city + "</p>";
      html += "<p class='popup'>" + r.phone + "</p>";
      html += "<p class='popup'>" + r.location.street + ", " + r.location.state + " " + r.location.postcode + "</p>";
      html += "<p class='popup'>" + r.dob + "</p>";
      html += "</div>";
      html += "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";
    $("#employeeList").html(html);
  }
});
$("#employeeList").on("click", "li", function(event) {
   var myclone = $(this).clone();
   $(".modal").html(myclone);
   // seems less than useful?  event.preventDefault();
   $(".overlay").show(); // put last to avoid "flash" on insertion of content
})
$(".overlay").on("click", function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
* {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
   

body,
html {
  background-color: #eff2f5;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
}

li img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px lightgray solid;
  min-width: 400px;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
}

p {
  color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#main {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal {
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay hidden">
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
<h1>Awesome Startup Employee Directory</h1>
<div id="employeeList"></div>
```